# How to validate string against XML schema entry using .Net

Tags: validation, xsd

I have a string (source string) and XML schema string.

How do I validate this string against the schema entry? I do not need to validate whole XML document, just check if the string matches the certain XML schema entry.

I found it extremely cumbersome to wrap the string to XML document and then validate against all the schema, is there more light approach?

Comment: You should try to accept answers, otherwise people won't be willing to answer them after a while. Especially when you've asked 9 things and accepted 0 answers.

Comment: @Oded So... where are those answers which he should accpet?

Comment: Here is one of your questions with answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2042318/1583